# Yii2 mysql_real_escape_string

Tags: php, yii2

Below is the my code :

```
<?php
$sql2 = "Select * from table ";
for($i=0;$i<count($val);$i++){
$sql2.=" where(column1 LIKE '%".$val[$i]."%' OR "
    . "column2 LIKE '%".$val[$i]."%' OR "
    . "column3 LIKE '%".$val[$i]."%' OR "
    . "column4 LIKE '%".$val[$i]."%' OR "
    . "column5 LIKE '%".$val[$i]."%' OR "
    . "column6 LIKE '%".$val[$i]."%' OR "
    . "column7 LIKE '%".$val[$i]."%') ";
}
```

Now how to add mysql_real_escape_string here ?

option is like to do ->where('status=:status', [':status' => $status]) but here how can i pass such params ?

Comment: *"Now how to add mysql_real_escape_string here ?"* - **A: Don't**. Use a prepared statement, you'll probably thank me for it ;-)

Comment: Try something like `-where("column1 LIKE CONCAT('%', :val, '%')", [':val' => $val[$i]])`

Comment: @Barmar I got your point but how to create sql string with that ?

Comment: I don't know, I don't use Yii2.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like below with `Query` in yii2.And you have to add Query in header.

```
use yii\db\Query;

$query = new Query;
$query->select('*')
      ->from('table')
      ->where(['=','status',$status]);
for($i=0;$i<count($val);$i++){
      $query->orWhere(['like',column1,$val[$i]]);
}
    $command = $query->createCommand();
```

Comment: hope this will help you

Answer (score 1):

First of all, **mysql_** extension is deprecated and Yii do not use it.
You need to escape query parameters.

Solution, based on your question:

```
$query = new \yii\db\Query();
$query
    ->from('table')
    ->andFilterWhere([
        'OR',
        ['LIKE', 'column1', $val[0]],
        ['LIKE', 'column2', $val[1]],
        ['LIKE', 'column3', $val[2]],
        ['LIKE', 'column4', $val[3]],
        ['LIKE', 'column5', $val[4]],
        ['LIKE', 'column6', $val[5]],
        ['LIKE', 'column7', $val[6]]
    ]);
```

I thinks you need this:

```
$val = range(1,10);
$query = new \yii\db\Query();
$query->from('table');
foreach ($val as $v) {
    $query
        ->orFilterWhere([
            'OR',
            ['LIKE', 'column1', $v],
            ['LIKE', 'column2', $v],
            ['LIKE', 'column3', $v],
            ['LIKE', 'column4', $v],
            ['LIKE', 'column5', $v],
            ['LIKE', 'column6', $v],
            ['LIKE', 'column7', $v],
        ]);
}
```

**Additional info:**

```
$cc = $query->createCommand();
// debug query
var_dump($cc->rawSql); // returns SQL query with the substituted parameters
var_dump($cc->sql); // returns SQL query with placeholders 
var_dump($cc->params); // returns the placeholders 
// run query
var_dump($cc->queryAll());
```